# Unending Python Program which does not show results or errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to do a double integration which has matrices. When I run it, it does not show any result. Neither is it showing any errors. It just runs endlessly without any output. I don't think an infinite loop can be the problem as I am using 'for'. Is it because there are four 'for' loops and the system is incapable of doing it? Following is my code :

```
    f = np.zeros((1024,90))  

    D = 0.28                
    h = np.zeros(1024)
    h[0:512] = np.linspace(0,1,512)
    h[513:] = np.linspace(1,0,511) 

    for r in range(0,1024) :
      for phi in range(0,90) :
        for b in range(0,360) :
          for s in range(0,1024) :
            U = (D + r*sin(b-phi))/D
            l = math.pow(U,-2)
            k = D/(math.pow((math.pow(D,2)+math.pow(s,2)),0.5))   
            f[r,phi] = 0.5*l*k*q[s,b]*h[s]

    I =np.zeros((725,725))

    for x in range(0,725) :
      for y in range(0,725) :
        r = math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2)
        phi = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x))
        I[x,y] = f[r,phi]

    I8 = (((I - I.min()) / (I.max() - I.min())) * 255.9).astype(np.uint8)
    img = Image.fromarray(I8)
    img.save("Fanbeamreconstruction.png")
    im = Image.open("Fanbeamreconstruction.png")
    im.show()
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What output are you expecting? You don't do any `print`in your code.

Comment: I am expecting a grayscale image of the matrix I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadruple for loop will run for 1024*90*360*1024 = about 34 billion iterations in total. This might take a while to complete ;)

Also, you don't have any outputting instructions in the code you presented, so it shouldn't give any output anyway.

Comment: I have edited the code here. So ideally how much time should it take to show the output. And how do we make sure that it's not because of some error in the code?

Comment: For a quick check, you can add some `print` statements in the for loops - you will then see if the execution gets stuck somewhere and how long the calculations take. If this shows any problems, I guess it would be best to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The inner loop should be executed 33.9 billions of times.